# Ask user for input data then using that data to find XPath?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

As I'm currently new to working with Python Selenium, I'm stuck with this idea I have. Basically I want to ask the user to input text that can then be found on the website, so that my code can affect said text the user puts in. To do this I wanted the code to find the text on the website and find the XPath from the text provided by the user.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('')

driver.get("")
number_boi = input("Number?: ")
size = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), number_boi)]")
size.click()
```

Sample code is here to show what I was attempting to do, but when this code runs it clicks on something else on the website or it just doesn't work. Anything is appreciated, thanks! If any confusion arises from my question, please don't hesitate to ask for clarification :)

Comment: have you got a link to the website?

Comment: Hello! @Dunski, I was attempting to do this with Nike. Off my computer at the moment, but any Nike pair you find on their website should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

number_boi will not appear in your xpath as a variable but as the string name.
Depending what version of python do it like this..

Python3.6 +

```
size = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{number_boi}')]")
```

Earlier python

```
size = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(number_boi))
```

Comment: Honestly the closest I've gotten this to working! Thank you. But for some reason it doesn't work for all the sizes provided or it gives an error. https://www.nike.com/t/blazer-mid-77-vintage-mens-shoe-flCCX4/BQ6806-002 (that is the specific link I am working with). I know this is a bit of a hassle, but can you check this out? I'll be doing my best to figure this out as well haha. I would like for it to be as specific as possible by being able for the user to input something like "M 9.5", but again those darn errors lol (if you need the error, I'll gladly give it).

Comment: UPDATE: Got it it working, had to add quotation marks to the first one. Final results look like: size = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{number_boi}')]")

Comment: ok cool. well done. Ive updated my answer

Comment: I see, thanks for giving me the info I needed for those brackets. No idea I needed them so that it can be recognized as a variable. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using the code provided below was able to fix the issue! Appears that due to me not adding brackets, the code had believed that I was giving it a string name rather than an element/variable. Credit to @Dunski for pointing this out! :)

```
size = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{number_boi}')]")
```